# Update issue's details from Jenkins Pipeline using Jira Plugin

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy, jira-plugin

I have the [Jira Plugin](https://plugins.jenkins.io/jira/) installed and configured. I can run a basic query like:

```
def issue = jiraSearch(jql: "key = 'issueKey'");
```

From that, on only one issue on which I know the issueKey, **how can I update one default field**, let say `Fix versions` (so not custom field), from my Jenkins Pipeline ?

What do I need to put in this code ?

```
pipeline {
   agent any
   stages {
      stage('My Stage') {
            ...?
        }
    }
}
```

I've found this [JIRA Pipeline Steps](https://plugins.jenkins.io/jira-steps/#documentation) plugin, perhaps it'll be necessary. Even with the [Jira Plugin documentation](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/jira/) it's unclear for me how it works.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a Jira instance with me to test right now but if I remember correctly, fix version is a [Jira custom field](https://confluence.atlassian.com/adminjiraserver/managing-custom-fields-1047552711.html). This means that you have to use the [issue field updater](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/jira/#stepclass-issuefieldupdatestep-jira-issue-custom-field-updater) to update this field. To do that you have to pass in the issue selector (to specify which issue you are changing), the  custom field ID and the value you need for that field.

You can find the custom field ID [like this](https://confluence.atlassian.com/jirakb/how-to-find-id-for-custom-field-s-744522503.html).

Then you would issue the update with:

```
step([$class: 'hudson.plugins.jira.pipeline.IssueFieldUpdateStep', 
    issueSelector: $issue, 
    fieldId: $customfieldid
    fieldValue: "new field value"
])
```

Note that since I don't have a Jira instance with me I can't verify that the above snippet will work. I'm just giving you an idea as to how it works based on my previous experience and looking at the docs.

Comment: Thanks for your help ! I've check as you suggested and it's a default field, not a custom field. Moreover, I'm always stuck in writing my Pipeline because it expects brackets for the `step` keyword. So `stage('text') { step([...]) }` will raise an error. How am I supposed to write it ?

Answer (score 0):

With simple API call you can edit the whole issue following the [API documentation](https://developer.atlassian.com/cloud/jira/platform/rest/v3/api-group-issues/#api-rest-api-3-issue-issueidorkey-put).
Just check what the GET returns and then adapt your PUT request.